# Split and reverse string purely with regular expression

Tags: python, graphite, graphite-carbon

First off: Yes, I know that trying to accomplish this purely with regular expressions is foolish, but I need to do this within the context of Carbon Rewrite Rules which are essentially Python regular expressions, eg:

```
^collectd\.([a-z0-9]+)\. = \1.system.
```

I'm trying to migrate our monitoring systems from a Nagios-based system to one based on Collectd. However, collectd's `write_graphite` plugin is hard-coded to produce metrics named `$prefix.host_example_com.$metric` and our existing metrics are stored as `$prefix.com.example.host.$metric`.

Note: The hostnames do not have a fixed number of sections, they might be `bar.foo`, `baz.bar.foo`, `bif.baz.bar.foo`, etc.

So basically it seems to boil down to accomplishing this within a single `re.sub()` call.

So far I've got:

```
metric  = 'collectd.foo_bar_baz.some.metric'
pattern = r'^collectd\.(?:([^_.]+)_?)+(.*)$'
print re.sub(pattern, metric, r'\1 \2')
```

Which outputs: `baz .some.metric` and I can't even get it to repeat the capture group, let along have the first idea about how to reverse and join an arbitrary number of backreferences.

Is such a thing even possible in a single `re.sub()` call or should I just resign myself to a fate of terribly named/organized metrics and queries full of wildcards?

Comment: I haven't used the `re` module as much as I otherwise could, but the idea of "reversing" a string doesn't sound do-able using regular languages (the language theory concept on which regular expressions are built).  That would require a stack on which you push each element of the list that you want to reverse, and then building a string from the pop order of that list.  That would be more than a standard regular language could handle, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It might be possible using a PCRE recursive regexp.

Comment: I take that back. While that can be used to match a recursive pattern, I don't know how it could be used in the replacement part to put them back together.

Comment: Can multiple rewrite rules apply to a single string?  It should be possible to match a single section at one end and move it to the other end - make enough copies of that rule to equal the largest possible number of sections.

Comment: Yeah I figured that this was a longshot. I guess I'll have to write some ugly configs and also maybe submit a patch for the collectd plugin. Thanks all!